# Element Visibility trigger doesn't trigger even in Preview mode

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

I'm working with a website built in Drupal. Recently, the website owner requested adding link clicks and banner impressions tracking. I easily managed to set up link clicks in Tag Manager; the tracking data is visible in Analytics.

However, when trying to set up banner impressions with Element Visibility, the event doesn't trigger even in Preview mode.

Here's the trigger configuration:
[image: Trigger configuration]

I've tried with and without Observe DOM changes enabled. I've also tried .banner CSS Selector and even ID selection method.

Here's the tag configuration:
[image: Tag configuration]

Any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: Looks like the selector is wrong. Did you test the selector in devtools?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the website administrator hasn't installed the right tag manager code in  and . It solved the problem.

If anyone runs into a similar problem, besides checking the source code of the page where you're trying to trigger the event, you may also change the trigger to something simpler, like a `div` CSS selector and 1% visibility.

Make sure the element is actually visible on the website and has height greater than 0.